# TelegramAPIError: Bad Gateway (aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

I create a bot that notifies the user at certain times, but from time to time gives this error

```
dispatcher.py [LINE:390] ERROR | 2022-10-03 04:10:16,846 : Cause exception while getting updates.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 381, in start_polling
    updates = await self.bot.get_updates(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 110, in get_updates
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 231, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 128, in check_result
    raise exceptions.TelegramAPIError(description)

aiogram.utils.exceptions.TelegramAPIError: Bad Gateway
```

I think this problem is on the telegram side itself and is solved via webhook, but I don't want to use them.

Comment: Are you trying to post something on to the server? try doing a multipart post

Comment: I'm not trying to put anything on the server.

Comment: Check you api.telegram.org connectivity

Comment: @Oleg The connection is normal, the Internet is stable.